# Access denied to Cloud SQL randomly

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

My app has been connecting perfectly fine to my Cloud SQL instance for the past 10 months, since I started using it. But now, all of a sudden, I'm getting access denied errors that read:

```
OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database '<<name of database>>'")
```

My script is a python script that reads:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/<<instance name>>', db='<<database name>>')
```

I've tried adding new users, using a password, etc. even though I never had to do this before and it still rejects my app.

Also, I am not sure if this is related but I get a 404 error when I try to go to my .appspot.com URL.

I created a new project to test this and that .appspot.com URL gives the same error.

Comment: I read of sporadic problems once and it worked for some users at https://`sameaddr` til fixed

Answer (score 0):

Your Python script does not define a user. Which is AFAIK still required, even when connecting from within the same App Engine project.

So instead of:
`db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/[instance_connection_name]',    db='[database_name]')`

The connection should be declared like so:
`db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/[instance_connection_name]', db='[database name]', user='root')`